# Returning a string as a list?

Tags: python, string, list

For example, I want to return This

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;']
```

as

```
lst = ['apple', 'banana', [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2]]
```

I don't know how to finish this:

```
for i in lst:
    i[2] = ????
```

Comment: `[float(y.split('=')[-1]) for y in x.split(';') if y]`

Comment: @ wpercy , what is y and x

Comment: @Comp I've added an answer that should help you, but `x` is the input string and `y` becomes each element of `x.split(';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to make this a one-liner:

```
>>> x = 'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;'
>>> values = [float(y.split('=')[-1]) for y in x.split(';') if y]
```

This will split `x` on `;` which will result in

```
>>> x.split(';')
['Total=60.4 (1)=12.2', '(2)=18', '(3)=18', '(4)=12.2', '']
```

Then, for each element of `x`, which we will call `y`, we split again on the equals sign (`=`), giving us

```
>>> [y.split('=') for y in x.split(';')]
[['Total', '60.4 (1)', '12.2'],
 ['(2)', '18'],
 ['(3)', '18'],
 ['(4)', '12.2'],
 ['']]
```

the `if y` part of the comprehension will exclude all empty strings (like the last element in the list above), and the `[-1]` will grab the last element from each value of `y`. In this case, those are the values we want, but they're all strings. So the last thing we'll do is cast them as `float`s, giving us:

```
>>> values = [float(y.split('=')[-1]) for y in x.split(';') if y]
>>> values
[12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use regex to find the desired numbers

```
import re
a='Total=60.4 (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;'
map(float,(re.findall('(?=\=(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|\d{1,}))',a.split(" ")[1])))
```

Output

```
[12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2]
```

For given example

```
import re
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'Total=60.4  (1)=12.2;(2)=18;(3)=18;(4)=12.2;'] 
lst[2]=map(float,(re.findall('(?=\=(\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|\d{1,}))',lst[2].split()[1])))
print(lst)
```

Output

```
['apple', 'banana', [12.2, 18.0, 18.0, 12.2]]
```